# How to create file with directory

Tags: go

I am trying to create a file with directories and sub-directories. But Go always returns an error saying path not found. I want to create file with directories.
I want a, b, c directories to be created(a/b/c) and c directory should have a file d.txt
I have used os.Create and os.OpenFile

```
_, cerr := os.OpenFile("a/b/c/d.txt")
    if cerr != nil {
        log.Fatal("error creating a/b/c", cerr)
    }

_, cerr := os.Create("a/b/c/d.txt")
    if cerr != nil {
        log.Fatal("error creating a/b/c", cerr)
    }
```

path error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create all missing directories and then the file with one function call. You can create all missing directories, and then the file, as follows:

```
_,err:=os.MkdirAll("a/b/c",perm)
f, err:=os.Create("a/b/c/d.txt")
```

You can also achieve this with:

```
name:="a/b/c/d.txt"
os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(name),perm)
f, err:=os.Create(name)
```